# How to refer in JsDoc (VS Code / IntelliSense) to class from another file without direct import?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, es6-modules, jsdoc, javascript-intellisense

### Problem

I use Visual Studio Code and use IntelliSense with JsDoc comments.
I have two modules with class declarations:

```js
/**
 * This is Foo class 
 */
export default class Foo {
    constructor() {}
}
```

and

```js
/**
 * This is Bar class 
 */
export default class Bar {
    constructor() {}

    /**
     * Init Bar from Foo
     * @param {Foo} foo instance of Foo
     * @returns {Bar}
     */
    static initFromFoo(foo) {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

Class `Bar` use `Foo` as param for the method `initFromFoo` but IntelliSense doesn't understand that `@param Foo` is referred to `class Foo` and don't work properly and says that `foo:any`,

https://imgbbb.com/images/2019/09/24/image517c0ec9d1027ac9.png

**How can I make IntelliSense work well?**

### What I have tried

1. Import `./foo` into `./bar`- this makes IntelliSense work well but I don't need this import I need just reference to the type definition.
2. Add reference to another file like in TypeScript `/// <reference path="./foo">` - no effects
3. Create `jsconfig.json` file with the next content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "checkJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

no effects too. It just highlights error `Cannot find name 'Foo'.ts(2304)`

**P.S.** It looks like IntelliSense limitation that related to ES6 modules. Because if I remove `export/import` from both files IntelliSense work as expected

https://i.ibb.co/CPL1gJC/image.png

https://i.ibb.co/xmXqzSk/image.png

**P.S.S.** Sorry for links to images my repo is too low for image posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to import type by **import(*path*)** statement.
For example:

```js
/**
 * Init Bar from Foo
 * @param {import('./foo').default} foo instance of Foo
 * @returns {Bar}
 */
static initFromFoo(foo) {
    return new Bar();
}
```

OR

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import('./foo').default} Foo
 *
 * Init Bar from Foo
 * @param {Foo} foo instance of Foo
 * @returns {Bar}
 */
static initFromFoo(foo) {
    return new Bar();
}
```

*P.S.* It is hack only for Visual Studio Code. It isn't valid JsDoc.